# isset function not working properly

Tags: php, session-variables, isset

The page is unable to see the login form whose code is written under the isset function statement. I have written the code correctly and have executed it many times , but now the code written inside the isset statement does not works. here is the code:-

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "<p style=\"font-color: #ff0000;\"> Catogoies </p>";

echo '<link href="var/www/html/sample.css" rel="stylesheet">';



require_once('../html/conn.php');
$query = "select * from catogories";
mysqli_select_db($dbc, 'odit');
$retrieve = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

if(!$retrieve)
{
    die(mysqli_error($query));
}
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($retrieve, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
echo "<p style=\"font-color: #ff0000;\">".'<a href="cats.php?        catogory='.urldecode($row["Name"]).'">'.$row["Name"].'</a>'."</p>";
$_SESSION['cat']=$row["Name"]; 
}
if(!($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}if(isset($_SESSION['lgout']))//the variable logout intialization line
{
if($_SESSION['lgout']!=1||$_SESSION['signup']){
echo "Hello : ".'<a href = "profile.php">'.$_SESSION['unme'].'</a>';    echo "<br><br>";
echo '<a href="logout.php">'."Logout";}
else { 
include 'lform.php'; echo "<br><br>";   

echo '<a href="Sign_up.php">'."Sign up"."<br>";
} }
mysqli_close($dbc);
//include 'lform.php';
?>
<br>
<a href = 'adding_catogory.php'>Create a New Catogory</a><br><br>
<a href = 'Log_in.php'></a>

<?php
$db = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "oddittor", "Odit@123", "odit");
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['l_id']);
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['pswd']);
$sql="SELECT * from users where usrName='$username' and pswrd =    '$password'"; 

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result) or die(mysqli_error($db));
if($count>0) {

    $_SESSION['unme']=$username; //This is the global session variable...used for storing the variables across the pages.
    $_SESSION['lgout']=0;
    header('Location : session.php'.$_SESSION['unme']);
    header("Location : Homepage.php".$_SESSION['unme'].$_SESSION['lgout']); header( "refresh:0;url=Homepage.php" );

    $_SESSION['unme']=$username;
}

else {
    $error = "Invalid Details! Please Renter them"; }
}
?>
```

Here the problem is in the

```
if(isset($_SESSION['lgout']))
```

line if, I remove this line i can see the login page form but by doing so, I get the error of undefined variable logout whenever, I open the page for the first time.

here is the logout script

```
<html>
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['lgout']=1;
$_SESSION['signup']=0;
echo ' You have been successfully logged out';
header('Location : Homepage.php'.$_SESSION['lgout']);header(     "refresh:0;url=Homepage.php" );

?>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect? You're destroying the session right after you start it?

Comment: Error in line 3: Without start why put close `} }`

Comment: `$db = @mysqli_connect(...`. Don't suppress error messages, handle them instead.

Comment: You are open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is not as secure as one might wish...

Comment: Even when i removed session destroy the same problem persisted

Comment: Where and how are you setting `$_SESSION['lgout']`? If `isset($_SESSION['lgout'])` evaluates as false, it's obviously not set (or contains `null`) and the code you should show us is where you're setting it, not using it...

Comment: the value of $_SESSION['lgout'] is in if($count>0) {

    $_SESSION['unme']=$username; //This is the global session variable...used for storing the variables across the pages.
    $_SESSION['lgout']=0;
    header('Location : session.php'.$_SESSION['unme']);
    header("Location : Homepage.php".$_SESSION['unme'].$_SESSION['lgout']); header( "refresh:0;url=Homepage.php" );

    $_SESSION['unme']=$username;
}

Comment: Since you're setting the session `$_SESSION['lgout']` in your logout script, it will never be set until your logout script runs for the first time. You should do it the other way around. Set `$_SESSION['loggedIn']` to `true` if the user is logged in and show the login form if it isn't `true` (or doesn't exist)

Comment: Btw.. your logout script is invalid. You can't send headers after you have output something on the screen. You're appending `1` on the URL you're redirecting to. You should have an `exit;` after a `header('location: ...');`. Your second header is not needed. There are so many errors in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove

```
session_destroy();
```

As you can access all `$_SESSION` values.

Your queries not secured. Use `Prepared Statements` instead of your all queries.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: the problem is still present

Comment: Once remove the `session_destroy` your code is redirecting to `Homepage.php`. No error is show.

Comment: My page is unable to show the login form, the include statement in which the code for login form is written.

Comment: Just I'm putting the static values. Here no errors. Please check once.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your

`session_start();`

globally on the start of page. As it's not able to get `$_SESSION` object.